# UITableViewCell changeable content based data coming from server

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am struggling this issue which is related to `UITableViewCell`. I have a subclass `UITableViewCell` called `ApplicantMessageCell` and it has some subviews, labels, imageviews etc. Top part of it does not depend on the state. Just gets the data, changes labels text and imageView's image.

However for the bottom part I have completely different 3 subclasses of `UIView` for each state coming in. I need to show related `UIView` subclass at the bottom part of `ApplicationMessageCell`. But I could not find a way to do it.

- Of course, I could create different `UITableViewCell` subclasses for each state but I didnot want to go that road beacuse this is just one case, I have more.
- I tried to create a subclass of `UIView` which will behave like `UILabel` when it comes to resizing itself. I could not manage to it.
- Lastly, I know adding each `UIView` subclass regarding each state and explicitly showing the one/hiding rest would solve it but I believe there are better ways to achieve this.

I did not share any code because I think this more of a theoretical question, but of course I will if anyone requests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's very difficult to answer "theoretical" questions. For performance, you want to do as little as needed when the cell is *reused* - so if you have 5 "constant" elements plus 1 "variable" element (such as, one of three "states"), create the views in the cell init and show/hide them on reuse. If you have 5 *distinctly different cell layouts*, create 5 different cell classes.

Comment: I see. I have 1 variable element. So you suggest I should add the views regarding every state as subview to cell initially. When the cells are being reused, I should just change the those views visibility? Even if I get it right, I could not figure out how to achieve it using constraints. Do you have any suggestions for that? @DonMag

Comment: Again, difficult to answer "theoretical" ... one method is to put the 3 "variable" views in a vertical stack view. When you set a view hidden, it *stays* there but the stack view removes its "occupying" frame.

Comment: will that just work with `.isHidden`?

Comment: And feel free to give advice to help me getting this question out of "theoretical" zone?

Comment: Are you designing your cell(s) as Prototypes in Storyboard? Or are you creating them strictly through code?

Comment: They are all code. No storyboard or xib whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example...

The cell class has two labels, a stack view, and 3 views (red, green, blue) with varying heights to use as the "show or not" views:

- First label is constrained to the Top
- Second label is constrained to the bottom of First label
- stack view is constrained to the bottom of Second label **and** to the bottom of the cell (contentView, of course)

Three views of varying heights are then added to the stack view. Presumably, the constraints on the subviews of your different views will determine their respective heights. For this example, they are set to 40, 80 and 160.

Review the comments in the following code - it should be pretty self-explanatory:

```
class ApplicantMessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let subLabel = UILabel()
    
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    
    let viewA = UIView()
    let viewB = UIView()
    let viewC = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        [titleLabel, subLabel, stackView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain titleLabel at top
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            
            // subLabel 8-pts below titleLabel
            subLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            subLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            subLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // stackView 8-pts below subLabel
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // constrain stackView bottom to bottom
        // this will avoid auto-layout complaints while the cells are configured
        let c = stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor)
        c.priority = .defaultHigh
        c.isActive = true
        
        // UI element properties
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        subLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        viewA.backgroundColor = .red
        viewB.backgroundColor = .green
        viewC.backgroundColor = .blue

        // you'll be filling the views with something to determine their heights
        //  but here we'll just set them to 40, 80 and 160 pts
        
        for (v, h) in zip([viewA, viewB, viewC], [40.0, 80.0, 160.0]) {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(h)).isActive = true
        }
        
    }
    
    func fillData(_ top: String, sub: String, showViews: [Bool]) -> Void {
        titleLabel.text = top
        subLabel.text = sub
        // hide views as defined in showViews array
        for (v, b) in zip(stackView.arrangedSubviews, showViews) {
            v.isHidden = !b
        }
    }
    
}

struct ApplicationStruct {
    var title: String = ""
    var subTitle: String = ""
    var showViews: [Bool] = [true, true, true]
}

class FarukTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var theData: [ApplicationStruct] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for i in 0..<20 {
            // cycle through views 1, 2, 3
            let b1 = i % 3 == 0
            let b2 = i % 3 == 1
            let b3 = i % 3 == 2
            let a = [b1, b2, b3]
            let d = ApplicationStruct(title: "Title \(i)", subTitle: "", showViews: a)
            theData.append(d)
        }
        
        // just to test, set more than one view visible in a couple cells
        theData[11].showViews = [true, false, true] // red and blue
        theData[12].showViews = [false, true, true] // green and blue
        theData[13].showViews = [true, true, false] // red and green
        theData[14].showViews = [true, true, true]  // all three

        tableView.register(ApplicantMessageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ApplicantMessageCell
        
        let d = theData[indexPath.row]
        
        let subStr = "showViews: " + d.showViews.description
        
        c.fillData(d.title, sub: subStr, showViews: d.showViews)
        
        return c
    }
    
}
```

Result where first row shows "ViewType1" second row shows "ViewType2" and third row shows "ViewType3" ... then the rows cycle, until we hit row "Title 11" where we've set a few rows to show more than one of the "subview types":

[image]

Comment: works like a charm, thank you. I did made some specific tweaks for my case though. really appreciated @DonMag